# React native Web build failed with webpack, errors in node_modules

Tags: react-native, webpack

I am getting errors when runnning npm run start to build my react native application on web and it seems like many dependencies are incompatible with webpack. All errors reference node_modules which make me lead to this conclusion but I am not sure; any recommendations to solve these errors would be really appreciated.
There is one error on App.js and I am attaching the code of my App.js, webpack.config.js, and package.json. The errors are:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/module/assets/back-icon-mask.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/module/index.js 1:4119-4157
 @ ./node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/module/views/Header/Header.js 1:327-364
 @ ./node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/module/index.js 1:1939-1971
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:802-836
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/module/assets/back-icon.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/lib/module/index.js 1:4085-4118
 @ ./node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/module/views/Header/Header.js 1:327-364
 @ ./node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/module/index.js 1:1939-1971
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:802-836
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./App.js 1:614-637
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'module-alias' in 'C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0'
 @ ./src/index.js 1:156-173

ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/common/Base64.js 1:207-265
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/binaryToBase64' in 'C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\lib\common'
 @ ./node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/common/index.js 1:1020-1039
 @ ./node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/lib/index.js 1:944-992
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:1492-1530
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/SharedEventEmitter.js 1:207-268
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter' in 'C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\lib\internal'
 @ ./node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/lib/internal/index.js 1:2429-2460
 @ ./node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/lib/index.js 1:1007-1057
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:1492-1530
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/utils/useResponsiveQuery/useResponsiveQuery.web.js 1:225-299
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/StyleSheet/createCompileableStyle' in 'C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\native-base\lib\module\utils\useResponsiveQuery'
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/utils/useResponsiveQuery/index.js 1:442-473
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/core/NativeBaseProvider.js 1:736-774
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/core/index.js 1:671-702
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/index.js 1:11014-11031
 @ ./src/screens/TabScreen.js 1:762-784
 @ ./src/containers/main/Newsagreggation/newsagreggationnavigator.js 1:784-828
 @ ./src/containers/main/TabNavigator.js 1:786-839
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:1039-1080
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/utils/useResponsiveQuery/useResponsiveQuery.web.js 1:339-400
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/StyleSheet/i18nStyle' in 'C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\native-base\lib\module\utils\useResponsiveQuery'
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/utils/useResponsiveQuery/index.js 1:442-473
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/core/NativeBaseProvider.js 1:736-774
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/core/index.js 1:671-702
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/index.js 1:11014-11031
 @ ./src/screens/TabScreen.js 1:762-784
 @ ./src/containers/main/Newsagreggation/newsagreggationnavigator.js 1:784-828
 @ ./src/containers/main/TabNavigator.js 1:786-839
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:1039-1080
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/utils/useResponsiveQuery/useResponsiveQuery.web.js 1:415-474
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/StyleSheet/compile' in 'C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\native-base\lib\module\utils\useResponsiveQuery'
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/utils/useResponsiveQuery/index.js 1:442-473
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/core/NativeBaseProvider.js 1:736-774
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/core/index.js 1:671-702
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/index.js 1:11014-11031
 @ ./src/screens/TabScreen.js 1:762-784
 @ ./src/containers/main/Newsagreggation/newsagreggationnavigator.js 1:784-828
 @ ./src/containers/main/TabNavigator.js 1:786-839
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:1039-1080
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/utils/useResponsiveQuery/useResponsiveQuery.web.js 1:517-582
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-web/dist/exports/StyleSheet/styleResolver' in 'C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\native-base\lib\module\utils\useResponsiveQuery'
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/utils/useResponsiveQuery/index.js 1:442-473
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/core/NativeBaseProvider.js 1:736-774
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/core/index.js 1:671-702
 @ ./node_modules/native-base/lib/module/index.js 1:11014-11031
 @ ./src/screens/TabScreen.js 1:762-784
 @ ./src/containers/main/Newsagreggation/newsagreggationnavigator.js 1:784-828
 @ ./src/containers/main/TabNavigator.js 1:786-839
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:1039-1080
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-image-picker/src/index.ts 15:36
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:36)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export * from './types';
|
> export function launchCamera(options: CameraOptions, callback?: Callback) {
|   return Platform.OS === 'web'
|     ? webCamera(options, callback)
 @ ./src/containers/main/addPost/addPostScreen.js 1:857-893
 @ ./src/containers/main/addPost/addPostNavigator.js 1:316-342
 @ ./src/containers/main/TabNavigator.js 1:529-566
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:1039-1080
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./app.json
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\app.json: Missing semicolon. (2:8)

  1 | {
> 2 |   "name": "GoodNews"
    |         ^
  3 |
  4 | }
    at instantiate (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:72:32)
    at constructor (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:367:12)
    at FlowParserMixin.raise (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3678:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.semicolon (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:4123:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15399:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5978:18)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14930:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14782:17)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5952:24)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15441:25)
 @ ./src/index.js 1:184-206

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/glyphmaps/MaterialCommunityIcons.json
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\glyphmaps\MaterialCommunityIcons.json: Missing semicolon. (2:14)

  1 | {
> 2 |   "ab-testing": 983497,
    |               ^
  3 |   "abacus": 988896,
  4 |   "abjad-arabic": 987944,
  5 |   "abjad-hebrew": 987945,
    at instantiate (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:72:32)
    at constructor (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:367:12)
    at FlowParserMixin.raise (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3678:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.semicolon (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:4123:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15399:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5978:18)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14930:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14782:17)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5952:24)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15441:25)
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons.js 1:358-408
 @ ./src/containers/main/TabNavigator.js 1:892-951
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:1039-1080
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-web/package.json
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\react-native-web\package.json: Missing semicolon. (2:9)

  1 | {
> 2 |   "_args": [
    |          ^
  3 |     [
  4 |       "react-native-web@0.18.9",
  5 |       "C:\\Users\\dasorto\\Desktop\\DOCS Alex\\ENews0"
    at instantiate (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:72:32)
    at constructor (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:367:12)
    at FlowParserMixin.raise (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3678:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.semicolon (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:4123:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15399:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5978:18)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14930:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14782:17)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5952:24)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15441:25)
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/utils.js 1:684-720
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/init.js 1:385-403
 @ ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/index.js 1:4013-4030
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:1199-1238
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./node_modules/sentiment/build/emoji.json
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\sentiment\build\emoji.json: Missing semicolon. (2:8)

  1 | {
> 2 |     "": 1,
    |         ^
  3 |     "❤": 3,
  4 |     "♥": 3,
  5 |     "": 3,
    at instantiate (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:72:32)
    at constructor (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:367:12)
    at FlowParserMixin.raise (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3678:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.semicolon (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:4123:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15399:10)
 Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5978:18)orto\Desktop\DOCS[..................] - : WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14930:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14782:17)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5952:24)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15441:25)
 @ ./node_modules/sentiment/lib/language-processor.js 1:11-41
 @ ./node_modules/sentiment/lib/index.js 1:218-249
 @ ./src/containers/main/home/homeScreen.js 1:1072-1092
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:1571-1615
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./node_modules/sentiment/languages/en/labels.json
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\sentiment\languages\en\labels.json: Missing semicolon. (2:11)

  1 | {
> 2 |   "abandon": -2,
    |            ^
  3 |   "abandoned": -2,
  4 |   "abandons": -2,
  5 |   "abducted": -2,
    at instantiate (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:72:32)
    at constructor (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:367:12)
    at FlowParserMixin.raise (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3678:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.semicolon (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:4123:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15399:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseExpressionStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5978:18)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatementContent (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14930:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14782:17)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatement (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5952:24)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:15441:25)
 @ ./node_modules/sentiment/languages/en/index.js 1:23-47
 @ ./node_modules/sentiment/lib/language-processor.js 1:57-89
 @ ./node_modules/sentiment/lib/index.js 1:218-249
 @ ./src/containers/main/home/homeScreen.js 1:1072-1092
 @ ./src/AppNavigator.js 1:1571-1615
 @ ./src/index.js 1:248-273

ERROR in ./node_modules/sentiment/languages/en/negators.json
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\dasorto\Desktop\DOCS Alex\ENews0\node_modules\sentiment\languages\en\negators.json: Missing semicolon. (2:10)

  1 | {
> 2 |     "cant": 1,
    |           ^
  3 |     "can't": 1,
  4 |     "dont": 1,
  5 |     "don't": 1,
```

App.js:

```
  import AppNavigator from './src/AppNavigator';
  import React from 'react';
  import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
  import {AuthProvider} from './src/AuthProvider';
  import {FireAuth} from './src/signupfunction';
  import RNBootSplash from 'react-native-bootsplash';

  const moduleAlias = require("module-alias");
  moduleAlias.addAliases({
  "react-native": require.resolve("react-native-web"),
   });
  moduleAlias();

  function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {//double check use of useeffect here
  setTimeout( () => {
  RNBootSplash.hide();
   }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return <NavigationContainer><AuthProvider>
  <FireAuth/>
  </AuthProvider></NavigationContainer>;
  // return <AuthProvider><NavigationContainer>
   //   <FireAuth/></NavigationContainer>
  //   </AuthProvider>;
  }

  export default App;
```

Webpack.config.js:

```
 const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
 var path = require('path');
 module.exports = {

 module: {
  rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js|\.jsx$/,
    use: {
      loader: "babel-loader",
      options: {
        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
      },
    },
    },
    {
    test: /.html$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "html-loader",
      },
    ],
    },
    ],
    },
   plugins: [
   new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
   template: "./public/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html",
  }),
  ],
  resolve: {

  alias: {

  "react-native": "react-native-web",
  myApp: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
   },

  extensions: [".web.js", ".js"]

   },
  devServer: {
   static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  port: 9000
  },
   };
```

package.json:

```
 {
 "name": "goodness",
 "homepage": "https://enews-2f2ec.web.app",
 "version": "0.0.1",
   "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "predeploy": "npm run build",
 "postinstall": "npm run build",
 "deploy": "firebase build",
 "android": "react-native run-android",
 "ios": "react-native run-ios",
  "start": "webpack-dev-server",
 "test": "jest --coverage && coveralls < coverage/lcov.info",
 "lint": "eslint .",
 "build": "webpack --mode=production",
 "web": "webpack serve --mode=development --config webpack.config.js",
 "transpile": "babel src/index.js --out-file src/index-transpiled.js"
 },
 "dependencies": {
 "@babel/cli": "^7.18.10",
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.19.0",
 "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
 "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.2",
 "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.1.2",
 "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
 "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.4.0",
 "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^15.4.0",
 "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^15.4.0",
 "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^15.4.0",
 "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.3",
 "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.3",
 "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
 "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.3",
 "babel-core": "^7.0.0-0",
 "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
 "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.1",
 "fbjs": "^3.0.4",
 "firebase": "^9.9.4",
 "html-loader": "^4.1.0",
 "moment": "^2.29.4",
 "native-base": "^3.4.13",
 "node": "14.16.1",
 "react": "18.0.0",
 "react-dom": "18.0.0",
 "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
 "react-native": "0.69.5",
 "react-native-bootsplash": "^4.3.2",
 "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
 "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
 "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
 "react-native-google-signin": "^2.1.1",
 "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.0",
 "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.0",
 "react-native-input-scroll-view": "^1.11.0",
 "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
 "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
 "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
 "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
  "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
  "react-native-select-dropdown": "^2.0.4",
  "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
  "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
  "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
  "react-native-web": "^0.18.9",
  "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",
  "react-responsive-combo-box": "^1.3.0",
   "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
  "sentiment": "^5.0.2",
  "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.19.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.0",
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.0",
  "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.1.0",
  "@svgr/webpack": "^6.3.1",
  "babel-jest": "^29.0.2",
  "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
  "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.18.9",
  "coveralls": "^3.1.1",
  "eslint": "^8.23.0",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
  "jest": "^29.0.2",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.72.2",
  "nyc": "^15.1.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
  "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
  "webpack": "^5.74.0"
  },
  "jest": {
   "preset": "react-native",
  "setupFiles": [
  "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
  ],
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "/node_modules/(?!native-base)/"
  ]
  }
  }
```